# Java: Passing Objects and Values

Tags: java, oop

I am new to the website and I'm also a beginner in Java and I'd appreciate someone to explain to me a few things in the following question and please excuse my knowledge.

**Which statement causes a compilation error?**

```
class X{
void f1() { System.out.println("XXX"); }
}
class Y extends X{
void f1() { System.out.println("YYY"); }
}
class Z extends X{
void f1() { System.out.println("ZZZ"); }
}

public class Testing {


static void g(X a)
{ a.f1(); }


public static void main(String args[]){
Y y = new Y();        // s1
g(y);                 // s2
Object obj = new Y(); // s3
obj.f1();             // s4
X x = new Z();        // s5
x.f1();               // s6
}
}
```

A few things are confusing me:

1- static void g(X a) it's a method named g and takes X which is the first class and also takes "a" as a parameter? why aren't they separated by a coma? what's "a" and a.f1();?

2- g(y); is this passing y object into the method g? How is it different from provoking? e.g.  y.g();

3- I know that to create an object first you need to choose the type (class name) then a name for that object then assign it to "new" and again the same type after "new". Why do these have another type after "new"?

Object obj = new Y();

X x = new Z();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> static void g(X a) it's a method named g and takes X which is the first class and also takes "a" as a parameter? why aren't they separated by a coma? what's "a" and a.f1();?

`g(X a)` is a method that takes an instance of `X` as a parameter. The parameter name is `a` and the type of the parameter is `X`.

> `g(y);` is this passing y object into the method g? How is it different from provoking? e.g. y.g();

Yes, you are indeed passing `y` into `g`. If you wrote `y.g()`, you are saying to call a method called `g` that is declared in `Y`. But there is no `g` method in `Y`, so this will cause a compiler error.

> I know that to create an object first you need to choose the type (class name) then a name for that object then assign it to "new" and again the same type after "new". Why do these have another type after "new"?

The first type is the type of your variable and is part of the variable declaration. A variable declaration looks like this:

```
Type name;
```

The second type (the one after the word `new`) is part of the constructor call. A constructor call is basically telling the computer to "create a new instance of this type please". These two types you write can be different, like this:

```
X obj = new Y();
```

Because an instance of `Y` *can* be put into a variable of type `X` because `Y extends X`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- static void g(X a) it's a method named g and takes X which is the
>   first class and also takes "a" as a parameter? why aren't they
>   separated by a coma? what's "a" and a.f1();?

`static void g(X a)` declares a method (called "g") which takes one argument (of class X`)` named `a`. In the method you will refer to that object with its name, "a", so `a.f1 ();` is just invoking `f1 ()` method, defined in class `X`, on `a`.

> g(y); is this passing y object into the method g? How is it different
>   from provoking? e.g. y.g();

The first part is obviously correct. It is different from calling method `g ()` on `y`, that would be possible only if you declared a method named `g ()` in`Y` class, but `g ()` is defined in `Testing` class.

> 3- I know that to create an object first you need to choose the type
>   (class name) then a name for that object then assign it to "new" and
>   again the same type after "new". Why do these have another type after
>   "new"?
>
> Object obj = new Y();
>
> X x = new Z();

This is due to [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). `Y` is-a `Object` (and `Z` is-a `X`), so you can assign that reference to an object of its super class.

But `f1 ()` method is not defined in `Object` class, so your `s4` isn't legal, even if the runtime type of `obj` variable is `Y`.
You can write:

```
((Y) obj).f1();
```

This is legal: you're casting obj to class `Y`, this will compile, but the cast will fail at runtime if `obj` is not of type `Y` (or a subclass of `Y`).